# How to link rows from one table to rows of another table in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have to four tables:

```
class Instrument(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    instrumentation = models.ManyToManyField(Instrumentation, verbose_name=_('instrumentation'), related_name='instrument', blank=True)

class Instrumentation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Entries to the table are:

```
row 1: name = violin, instrumentation = piano trio
row 2: name = piano, instrumentation = piano trio
row 3: name = cello, instrumentation = piano trio
```

Here are the other two tables:

```
class Ensemble(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

class EnsembleMember(models.Model):
    ensemble = models.ForeignKey(Ensemble, verbose_name=_('ensemble'), related_name='ensemble_member', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Person, verbose_name=_('member'), null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

row 1: name = person 1 (violinist), ensemble = Beau Arts Trio
row 2: name = person 2 (pianist), ensemble = Beau Arts Trio
row 3: name = person 3 (cellist), ensemble = Beau Arts Trio
```

How do I link Instrument with EnsembleMember? ForeignKey or ManyToManyField?

An Instrument to map to many different Ensemble Member.

```
row 1 in Instrument to row 1 in Ensemble Member
row 2 in Instrument to row 2 in Ensemble Member
row 3 in Instrument to row 3 in Ensemble Member
```

And have drop down options in admin.py

Comment: I also just recently started learning Django. I recommend making the many-to-many relationship explicit. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117113/how-to-make-django-manytomany-relationships-explicit-on-the-receiving-models-en   . I found it conceptually much easier as it explicitly gives you an 'assignment table' where you place the relationships between the instruments and the instrumentations.

Comment: Same thing for the ensemble vs member relationship. It's actually many-to-many, the EnsembleMember being the 'assignment table' or 'Ensemble-has-Member' table.

Comment: The third relationship is Member vs Instrument. Again, it's many-to-many as in "Member-plays-Instrument" .